Could there be a runaway thermonuclear fusion in ocean of heavy water?
Suppose that Super-Earth class planet exists where there is a hundred-kilometer-deep ocean of deuterium oxide.
If a sufficiently powerful thermonuclear bomb was detonated in depths of this ocean, could thermonuclear fusion of around material be triggered? Would such runaway thermonuclear fusion spread far enough to overwhelm entire world and turn it into plasma?

See Wikipedia's article on fusion.  "D-D fusion" (two deuterium atoms joining up) actually costs energy rather than producing it.  You'll need a lot of tritium in your set-up if you want a question with a fun answer.  But I mean by then you're practically making the planet as a bomb to begin with - probably has some flag logo on the side of it telling you who it's blowing up the stellar neighborhood on behalf of.

you want D-T fusion anyway, +17.6 MeV per fusion, 14.1 of it in a kinetic neutron travelling at 1/6th c

Pretty sure the point where runaway fusion occurs, words like "planet" and "ocean" would be meaningless, and be replaced with words like "gas giant", and "proto-star"...
Not to mention, "runaway fusion" would be "ignition" of a "star".

Hans Dominik, I think, had a similar idea, and then Oppenheimer...

I suppose a Super-Earth that makes fusion possible would conspicuously resemble the Sun ;-).

@MikeSerfas - yet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium_fusion disagrees quite strongly. "Deuterium (2H) is the most easily fused nucleus available to accreting protostars." One can easily get reasonable D-D cross sections at a few 100keV incident D, yielding a 2.5MeV neutron (and lesser 3He energy). Clearly this is an energy producing nuclear reaction. Yes, D-T has a higher cross section and Q value, but D-D works just fine.

True, I forgot about D-H fusion!  The post literally said "ocean of heavy water", and I went to D-T first because it's easiest.  I don't know if anyone makes H-bombs out of D+H with no tritium required!  Hmmm...

@MikeSerfas - D(D,n)3He is an energy-releasing fusion reaction all by itself. Again, D-T is "easier" (higher cross section at lower energies), but D-D works just fine.

Fusion bombs are activated by focusing the shock-wave produced by a fission bomb to strongly compress the suitable nuclei.
To achieve the desired compression the shock wave must converge into a smaller volume, while an uncontained explosion, be it nuclear or chemical, will tend to be divergent and will therefore not achieve the desired effect.
The answer to your question is no.

worse, they also need the neutron flux and gamma energy of the fission trigger to provide additional energy.
